# A count down timer for iOS using Time Interval Class

Tags: ios, swift, timer, stopwatch

Im using the following algorithm to make a stop watch. But what i needed is a timer to count down from a specific given time using the `TimeInterval` class so i needed to tweak this code a little bit to be able to implement the functionality i needed. Any help would be appreciated.

[Here is the link of the tutorial.](http://rshankar.com/simple-stopwatch-app-in-swift/#comment-3725)

```
@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
    let aSelector : Selector = “updateTime”
    timeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
}   

var startTime = TimeInterval()
var timeTimer = Timer()

func updateTime() {
    //let currentTime = date.parseDuration(timeString: "\(displayTimeLabel.text)")
    let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

    //Find the difference between current time and start time.
    var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

    //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)

    elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.
    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)

    elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)

    //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.
    let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

    //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

    //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel
    displayTimeLabel.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds):\(strFraction)"
}
```

Here is what i tried to do:

I used an extension to parse `String` to `TimeInterval`

```
    extension Date {

    func parseDuration(timeString:String) -> TimeInterval {

        guard !timeString.isEmpty else {
            return 0
        }

        var interval:Double = 0

        let parts = timeString.components(separatedBy:":")
        for (index, part) in parts.reversed().enumerated() {
            interval += (Double(part) ?? 0) * pow(Double(60), Double(index))
        }

        return interval
    }
}
```

Then added my needed start and end time. But the output is not correct. Im getting current time every time from the display.

```
let constTimeString = "15:04:46"

var date = Date()

var startTime = TimeInterval()
var timeTimer = Timer()

    func updateTimeAction() {

        timeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTime2), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = date.parseDuration(timeString: constTimeString)

    }

func updateTime2() {

         let currentTime = date.parseDuration(timeString: displayTimeLabel.text!)
        var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime
        print("elapsed: \(elapsedTime)")


        //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.

        let minutes = Int(elapsedTime / 60.0)
        print("minutes: \(minutes)")
        elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

        //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.

        let seconds = Int(elapsedTime)
        print("seconds: \(seconds)")
        elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)

        //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.

        let fraction = Int(elapsedTime * 100)
        print("fraction \(fraction)")
        //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

        let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
        let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
        let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

        //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel

        displayTimeLabel.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds):\(strFraction)"
    }
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: @matt i tried to tweak it and add a certain time like 04:45:10 and start my count down from there to 00:00:00 but cannot get it right.

Comment: "i tried to tweak it and add a certain time like 04:45:10" I do not see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: @matt ok i will put it. I didn't because it was useless.

Comment: It isn't useless: it's the _problem_. You need to show what _you_ are doing and explain what is going wrong. There is no point showing _other_ code; the problem is about _your real code_.

Comment: The code _you_ have shown appears to count _up_ from zero (starting at the moment when the Start button is tapped). Show what _you_ are doing to count _down_ from a fixed time.

Comment: @matt i added my tweak but i think there is something un logical at all im doing here. I think i will delete the question until i understand the whole logic behind the algorithm.

Comment: Now that I see your code, I can describe your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here:

```
let currentTime = date.parseDuration(timeString: displayTimeLabel.text!)
var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime
```

Don't fetch the value of `displayTimeLabel.text` at all, ever. It is *view*, not *model*. The only thing you should do with it is set it. Keep track of the *model* (the data you are manipulating) behind the scenes.

Okay, so go back to the way it was before. Record the start time when you start counting, and use the current time as the current time, and subtract to learn how much time has elapsed:

```
let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime
```

Okay, now you know how much elapsed time to subtract from `constTimeString` (parsed into a time interval) to learn what time string to display now in `displayTimeLabel.text`.

Comment: Okk...Thanks i will update my code and get back to you with the results. Thanks.